# Saving several numpy arrays to one csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have several different 'columns' I need to save to a CSV. Currently I do this:

```
f = open(out_csv, 'w', newline='') 
w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",", )
w.writerow(['id_a', 'id_b',
            'lat_a','lon_a',
            'lat_b','lon_b',
            'proj_metres'])
w.writerows(np.column_stack((
            id_labels[udist.row],
            id_labels[udist.col],
            points[udist.row],
            points[udist.col],
            udist.data)))
```

Perhaps not important but for completeness:

```
tree_dist = tree.sparse_distance_matrix(tree)
udist = sparse.tril(tree_dist, k=-1)
```

The dimensions are around 30 million by 7 columns (two of which are strings: id_labels) - so this takes a while (around 8 minutes) and uses a lot of RAM as I think python creates a new temporary object when I call np.column_stack so at a one point in time it holds double the data it needs.

I was hoping was there was a better way to create the CSV I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can open a file with *append* option and then use [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.arange(12).reshape((2, 6))
array2 = np.ones(18).reshape((3, 6))
with open('outputfile.csv', 'ab') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, array1, delimiter=',')
    np.savetxt(f, array2, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. I'm having a small problem with savetxt: `TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format specifier ('%f,%f')`. I import my array as  `dtype=(float, float)`, however can't save it as such

Comment: i can't understand your input array. it has 2 columns? can you write down it?

Comment: Sure if I do `points[:3]` I get: `[[  5.15317040e+01  -3.31830000e-02]
 [  5.10514740e+01  -4.04532300e+00]
 [  5.38018130e+01  -1.77162300e+00]]`

Comment: try with fmt='%f %f' instead of fmt=('%f', '%f')

Comment: Unfortunately no difference, if it helps this is how I import `points = np.genfromtxt(path_to_csv,
                       delimiter=',',
                       skip_header=1,
                       usecols=(0,1),
                       dtype=(float, float))`

Comment: you can use dtype=float

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105021/discussion-between-francesco-nazzaro-and-mptevsion).

Answer (score 1):

first, save file one by one to avoid memory problems.

let's consider 3 solutions:

```
a=np.rand(10000,7)

import csv
def testfile():
    with open('test.csv','w') as f :
        w=csv.writer(f)
        w.writerows(a)

def testsavetxt():
    np.savetxt('test.csv',a)


def testpickle():
    with open('test.pickle','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(a,f)
```

Some tests:

```
In [43]: %timeit testfile()
1 loops, best of 3: 576 ms per loop

In [44]: %timeit testsavetxt()
1 loops, best of 3: 442 ms per loop

In [45]: %timeit testpickle()
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
```

so savetext is slighty faster.

If csv is not requisite, [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#examples) offer a binary protocol, wich is 40x faster.

Comment: I like the np.savetxt option - what would you suggest I do to handle several arrays - use the same `np.column_stack(.. `? I'm having a bit of bother using 'ab' mode

Comment: what you do is not very readable, and you will have to do the same when loading. perhaps pandas can help you to collect your data ?

Comment: That would mean converting data to pandas, however. I think I will go with: `np.savetxt(out_csv,np.column_stack((
            id_labels[udist.row],
            id_labels[udist.col],
            points[udist.row],
            points[udist.col],
            udist.data))` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily fast, but:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
arr2 = np.array([11,12,13,14])
arr3 = np.array([21,22,23,24])
numpy_arrays = [arr1, arr2, arr3]

with open(out_csv, "w") as f:
    for values in zip(*numpy_arrays): # or just zip(arr1, arr2, arr3)
        for value in values:
            f.write(str(value) + ",")
        f.write("\n")
```

This won't use up much more memory than just the memory needed for your separate arrays.